# Declare array of double array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, double

I have declared my double array this way

```
double feature_values[] = {0.0003323988609746907, 0.6412162477054423, 9.545269768297, -1323.6125512135593, -1512.0718516647562, -2073.6020535721273, -2578.302701605687, 0.27304053703708875, 0.5580326301604825, 0.34912544310755905, 0.550917816717867, 49.7455110651867, 1821.15723334093, -61.3700045037962, -49.400686298507, 13.11111111111111, 26.0, 12.222222222222221, 18.0, 0.3111111111111111, 0.325, 0.4148148148148148, 0.43333333333333335, 0.5930328763108722, 0.7343377194812131, 0.23685155593995189, 0.6754530381265557, 0.16582557525922734, 0.009828988419922594, 0.00017475124235758377, 0.0003779194334627987, 0.0008100853061379151, 2.9387129701088046, 0.41880424639672703, 2.639057329615259, 0.0, 2.75, 2.807354922057604, 0.07124096827009982, 0 , 0.003, 0.1435385870250432, 0.5547574989867142, 0.1445909953802227};
    int index;
    for(int i=0;i<44;i++)
    {
        data[i].missing=-1;
        data[i].fvalue=feature_values[i];
        printf("feature[%d]=%.8f\n",i,feature_values[I]);
        predict_res(data,0,result);
    }
```

I have 6 different `feature_values` arrays. And I want to print result for each of them. Currently I need to change the array value every time to get the result. So, how do I declare array of double array and use it in for loop.

Comment: C or C++ ? Please pick one.

Comment: Updaetd @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: `double feature_value[6][44] = { { /*array1*/ }, { /*array2*/ }, { /* etc */ } };` -- and put your loop in a function.

Comment: use `std::array<std::array<double, 44>, 6>`

Comment: @paddy: Thanks for the example, I really appreciate if you can show how later array can be used in for loop. If you add you answer separately that will be great help for others too

Answer (score 1):

C++ has `std::array`, which has a `size()` member. If the size should very at runtime, use `std::vector`. It too has a `size()` member.

Answer (score 1):

> So How do I declare array of double array and use it in for loop.

The syntax of declaring an array of arrays is this:

```
double feature_values[6][44];
```

Note that elements of array are of same type. Hence, you cannot have sub arrays of different lengths.

> how do I use it in for loop.

In the same way as any other array. Example:

```
for(auto& sub_array : feature_values) {
    for(auto& element : sub_array) {
        use_value(element);
```

Comment: Thanks way looks good, but I really appreciate if you can add example showing how do I use it in for loop.

Comment: you should almost always prefer to use std::array over c-style arrays

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `std::array` for constant sized arrays. This example uses integers, but the concept is the same.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <array>

 typedef std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> arr_2d_t;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     arr_2d_t arr_2d;
     int num = 0;
     for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
         for (size_t e = 0; e < 3; ++e) {
             arr_2d[i][e] = num++;
         }
     }

     for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
         for (size_t e = 0; e < 3; ++e) {
             std::cout << arr_2d[i][e] << " ";
          }
          std::cout << std::endl;
     }
 }
```